# JQuery get current value of radio box selection

Tags: jquery

I have a form where I have radio button field such as:

```
<p><ul>
<li><label for="id_building_height_0"><input checked="checked" name="building_height"   value="1" id="id_building_height_0" type="radio" class="can_update_spans" /> 1 Story</label>    </li>
<li><label for="id_building_height_1"><input value="2" type="radio" class="can_update_spans" name="building_height" id="id_building_height_1" /> 2 Stories</label></li>
<li><label for="id_building_height_2"><input value="3" type="radio" class="can_update_spans" name="building_height" id="id_building_height_2" /> 3 Stories</label></li>
</ul></p>
```

My question is - how can I get the current value for whatever `$("input:checkbox[name='bulding_height']")` is currently set to?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('input:radio[name=bulding_height]:checked').val();
```

OR

```
$('[name=bulding_height]:checked').val();
```

Answer (score 2):

You have `input type radio but using input type checkbox in selector` you must use type radio. You also have given `wrong name in selector bulding_height should be building_height`

These all will give you value of selected radio button,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/7n4sK/3/)**

```
alert($("input:radio[name='building_height']:checked").val());
alert($(":radio[name='building_height']:checked").val());
alert($("[name='building_height']:checked").val());
```

To iterate through all radio button values you can use each

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/7n4sK/1/)**

```
$("input:radio[name='building_height']").each(function(){
     alert(this.value);
});​
```